# How to move files using FTP commands

Tags: ftp, command, rename, move

Path of source file is : `/public_html/upload/64/SomeMusic.mp3`

And I want to move it to this path : `/public_html/archive/2011/05/64/SomeMusic.mp3`

How can i do this using FTP commands?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

In FTP client:

```
rename /public_html/upload/64/SomeMusic.mp3 /public_html/archive/2011/05/64/SomeMusic.mp3
```

With FTP commands:

```
RNFR /public_html/upload/64/SomeMusic.mp3
RNTO /public_html/archive/2011/05/64/SomeMusic.mp3
```

source:
http://www.nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm

Comment: @Johan can I use one command line like: `RNFR /public_html/upload/64/SomeMusic.mp3 RNTO /public_html/archive/2011/05/64/SomeMusic.mp3`?

Comment: @user2545330 No, those are two separate FTP commands. Though in most (command-line) FTP clients, you cannot use those commands directly anyway (you can use `quote RNFR /public_html/upload/64/SomeMusic.mp3` and `quote RNTO /public_html/archive/2011/05/64/SomeMusic.mp3`). Why would you, if you can use the `rename /public_html/upload/64/SomeMusic.mp3 /public_html/archive/2011/05/64/SomeMusic.mp3`?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else will search for a solution to move files by ftp and will not find a solution:
As I encountered the same problem and even the `RNFR` and `RNTO` will not work like in my case:
I solved this by doing the following workaround:

```
mget files*.ext
cd /path/to/desired/folder/
mput files*.ext
```

This is twice the traffic (get and put) but for smaller files it is at least a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if you're getting Invalid Command when executing the RNFR and RNTO commands. Then use below you'll be able to move the files.

```
quote RNFR /from_path/filename.txt
quote RNTO /to_path/filename.txt
```

Comment: Do you really have an `ftp` client that does not support `rename` command? See [my comment to the @Johan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9461844/850848#comment67198460_9462082).