# Replace file on ftp server

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp

I'm searching a lot, but don't find any documentations or examples.

How to replace file from one directory to another on `ftp` server?

Any examples?

Comment: Do you want to do this from an iOS application?  https://github.com/nkreipke/FTPManager is an FTP library for iOS, but it doesn't support rename operations.  Perhaps you could modify it to implement RNFR and RNTO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461844/how-to-move-files-using-ftp-commands

Comment: That's too simple. Use this https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit

Answer (score 1):

There is no "move" command in the ftp protocol.

Check this one:

http://www.scriptftp.com/reference.php?go=topic133

Comment: `Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /reference.php on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use this library https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit to work with FTP on iOS. There are lot of examples in README file.

Comment: isn't it for OS X ?