# How to use ftp.rename() to move one directory to another in Python using ftplib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftplib, movefile

I have a `NAS` which having below file structures:

Say I have a movie directory "Terminator" which stores in below directory:

```
/media_staging/Terminator

    From Destination: /media_staging/Terminator
    To Destination:   /video/
    
    *Note: media_staging & video are in the same file level
```

So how could I use the `ftp.rename` to move the `'Terminator'` file from under `media_staging` to `video`?

Can I do it with something like this:

```
ftp.rename('/media_staging/Terminator','/video/Terminator')
```

As I could see it says there is permission issue in here...

May I know which is the right way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move files using FTP commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461844/how-to-move-files-using-ftp-commands)

Comment: I don't see `"permission issue"` in your question. Maybe you have to privilegets to access some folders. Maybe you will have to move files one by one.

Comment: Really?? Cannot move the whole directory by using 1 line code??

Comment: After I rechecked my code, now it prompt "550 rename: Invalid cross-device link."....

Answer (score 1):

After few tries, found that the reason why have such error is that the file 'Media_staging' & 'video' are in different share folders which is unable to move files, if in the same share folder, the ftp.rename & ftp commands can be executed fine.